# Copying data between models and saving children without entities duplicating themselves in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am having trouble saving children entities via Entity Framework / ASP Identity. It seems to be adding duplicates of everything that is added.

I have tried using a detached graph of the DrivingLicenceModel by TeamMember.DrivingLicence = null in the TeamMemberModel and then working with a detached graph by looking if there is new or old DrivingLicenceCategories but because DrivingLicence links back to TeamMember it causes TeamMember.DrivingLicenceId to be null as it cannot link back to TeamMember.

I have tried Manually adding the EntityState to the DrivingLicence and DrivingLicenceCategories but when I do that it complains that it cannot save two entities with the same primary key.

I assume this is because they way I am copying the entities but I after a lot of looking I am drawing a blank.

If there anyway to copy from TeamMemberRequestModel to TeamMemberModel and then save without the children trying to create clone copies of themselves?

Models

```
public class TeamMemberModel : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual DrivingLicenceModel DrivingLicence { get; set; }

    public void ShallowCopy(TeamMemberRequestModel src)
    {
         this.DateOfBirth = src.DateOfBirth;

         if (src.DrivingLicence != null)
         {
              if (this.DrivingLicence == null)
              {
                   this.DrivingLicence = new DrivingLicenceModel(src.DrivingLicence);
              }
              else
              {
                   this.DrivingLicence.ShallowCopy(src.DrivingLicence);
              }
         }
     }

     public TeamMemberModel() { }
}

public class DrivingLicenceModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamMember")]
    public string TeamMemberId { get; set; } 

    [JsonIgnore]
    public TeamMemberModel TeamMember { get; set; }

    public virtual List<DrivingLicenceCategoryModel> DrivingLicenceCategories { get; set; }

    public DrivingLicenceModel() { }

    public DrivingLicenceModel(DrivingLicenceModel src)
    {
        this.ShallowCopy(src);
    }

    public void ShallowCopy(DrivingLicenceModel src)
    {
        this.Id = src.Id;
        this.IsFullLicence = src.IsFullLicence;
        this.IssueDate = src.IssueDate;
        this.ExpiryDate = src.ExpiryDate;
        this.IssuingAuthority = src.IssuingAuthority;
        this.LicenceNumber = src.LicenceNumber;
        this.DrivingLicenceCategories = src.DrivingLicenceCategories;
        this.DrivingLicencePoints = src.DrivingLicencePoints;
    }
}

public class DrivingLicenceCategoryModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DrivingLicence")]
    public int DrivingLicenceId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DrivingLicenceModel DrivingLicence { get; set; }
}

public class TeamMemberRequestModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DrivingLicenceModel DrivingLicence { get; set; }
}
```

Context

```
public class TIERDBContext : IdentityDbContext<TeamMemberModel, RoleModel, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public TIERDBContext() : base("SARDBConnection") { }

    public DbSet<DrivingLicenceModel> DrivingLicences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DrivingLicenceCategoryModel> DrivingLicenceCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(string id, TeamMemberRequestModel teamMember)
 {
      TeamMemberModel CurrentTeamMember = await this.TIERUserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

      CurrentTeamMember.ShallowCopy(teamMember);

      await this.TIERUserManager.UpdateAsync(CurrentTeamMember);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create clone property into context class
.

In the context clases you could to use clone method that retiran the entity you send by parameters this duplicarse any entity you pass. Sorry for my english

hope you help

Answer (score 0):

After far to many hours working over this. I have come to an answer. The best way to deal with this is to simply deal with it is to add or attach all entities down the tree.

The controller now attaches all children unless they have an ID of 0, therefore new and uses add instead. Then I use this very useful extension I found here http://yassershaikh.com/c-exceptby-extension-method/ to compare lists to see added and deleted entities in the list. While I don't need the added part as the entity will already be marked to an add state as I use add() it does not harm and I want to use it later with add and delete state changing.

Controller

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(string id, TeamMemberRequestModel teamMember)
{
    TIERDBContext IdentityContext = (TIERDBContext)this.TIERUserManager.UserStore().Context;

    foreach (DrivingLicenceCategoryModel DrivingLicenceCategory in teamMember.DrivingLicence.DrivingLicenceCategories)
    {
        if (DrivingLicenceCategory.Id == 0)
        {
            IdentityContext.DrivingLicenceCategories.Add(DrivingLicenceCategory);
        }
        else
        {
            IdentityContext.DrivingLicenceCategories.Attach(DrivingLicenceCategory);
        }
    }

    foreach (DrivingLicencePointModel DrivingLicencePoint in teamMember.DrivingLicence.DrivingLicencePoints)
    {
        if (DrivingLicencePoint.Id == 0)
        {
            IdentityContext.DrivingLicencePoints.Add(DrivingLicencePoint);
        }
        else
        {
             IdentityContext.DrivingLicencePoints.Attach(DrivingLicencePoint);
        }
    }

    this.DetectAddedOrRemoveAndSetEntityState(CurrentTeamMember.DrivingLicence.DrivingLicenceCategories.AsQueryable(),teamMember.DrivingLicence.DrivingLicenceCategories, IdentityContext);

    this.DetectAddedOrRemoveAndSetEntityState(CurrentTeamMember.DrivingLicence.DrivingLicencePoints.AsQueryable(),teamMember.DrivingLicence.DrivingLicencePoints, IdentityContext);

    CurrentTeamMember.ShallowCopy(teamMember);

    await this.TIERUserManager.UpdateAsync(CurrentTeamMember);
}
```

I then use a generic that uses ExceptBy to work out what is added and delete from the old team member model to the new team member model.

```
    protected void DetectAddedOrRemoveAndSetEntityState<T>(IQueryable<T> old, List<T> current, TIERDBContext context) where T : class, IHasIntID
    {
        List<T> OldList = old.ToList();
        List<T> Added = current.ExceptBy(OldList, x => x.Id).ToList();
        List<T> Deleted = OldList.ExceptBy(current, x => x.Id).ToList();

        Added.ForEach(x => context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Added);
        Deleted.ForEach(x => context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Deleted);
    }
```

It works but it is far from great. It takes two DB queries, getting the original and updating. I just cannot think of any better way to do this.